# POST /riskyUsers/dismiss errors with http and powershell

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Trying to bulk dismiss all risky signons so my security team can start new.

It should be able to be done using this powershell code:

```
get-riskyUser -Top 5 -Filter "Riskstate eq 'AtRisk'" -Orderby RiskLastUpdatedDateTime | Invoke-DismissRiskyUser
```

But I get this error 5 times:

```
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Invoke-DismissRiskyUser_Dismiss" on target "Call remote 'RiskyUsersDismiss' operation".
Invoke-DismissRiskyUser_Dismiss: You cannot perform the requested operation.
```

I did authorize the scope for connect-graph with "IdentityRiskyUser.ReadWrite.All" as well assigned a P2 license to my admin account (which I think is stupid given the feature is a P1 feature)

This cmdlet calls the following API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/riskyusers-dismiss?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

so I dug up postman, got my self a shinny new bearer token based on a freshly minted app registration with the "IdentityRiskyUser.ReadWrite.All" API via app delegation which was then admin consented to then posted to the API using this body:

```
{
  "userIds": [
    "d9460130-07f0-43a9-9faa-df8c6635f4b7",
    "faff0a2a-143e-431d-bd44-99db3f4fc30d"
  ]
}
```

and got back:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Invalid user ids.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "a1dcf05e-bbf2-436a-9614-2a2d5b5d0fc0",
      "date": "2019-12-06T19:59:03"
    }
  }
}
```

I triple checked those IDs are valid, also tried all lower case in the attribute name.

At a loss for what to do next, anyone have any thoughts and/or where I can post to github to open a ticket against the code?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out a bunch of issues here. The PowerShell code didnt work because somehow I authorized read not readwrite on my first goes at it.

But thats not the whole story, next up, both the API and PowerShell were returning user object IDs for users no longer in Azure AD. These can never be dismissed via code nor the actual Azure Portal. I have a MS Case open for this.